# Show or hide an HTML element on base of selected option of a select list in Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want the `div` to be visible/hidden only if the second option is selected from my `select` list. Here is my code, which I am trying to achieve the functionality.

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: Datevalue">
</select> 

<div data-bind="visible: showSecond">
  <h3>
    If its the second option show me!!
  </h3>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function FilterModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.Datevalue = ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']);

    // boolean for showing the second select
    this.showSecond = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.Datevalue == 2;
    }, this);
  }

  $(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new FilterModel());
  });
});
```

Comment: `this.Datevalue` is an array. It will never have the value 2

Comment: Ahh, I wanted to select the second item in the array not the value, without stipulating 'Germany'.

Comment: I haven't used ko in a while, so i don't know how to do that anymore. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define self.selectedChoice = ko.observable() in your FilterModel() function and specify value: selectedChoice in your select list markup to get selected value of your select list.

```
<select data-bind="options: Datevalue , value: selectedChoice">
</select>
```

and then in your FilterModel function compare the selected value with your array index[1] value which is actually second option of your select list.

```
function FilterModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
    self.Datevalue = ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']);

    // boolean for showing the second select
    this.showSecond = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.selectedChoice() == this.Datevalue()[1];
   }, this);
}
```

Comment: My pleasure :-)